# xsltproc interprets XSL different

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, msxsl

I have

```
<price>59,00</price>
```

in XML and transform it with

```
<xsl:value-of select="(ceiling(((number(translate(text(), ',', '.'))*26))div 10)*10)"/>
```

in XSL, but I get different result in different processors.
In Liquid and `msxsl`, I get the correct result '1540', but in `xsltproc`, I got '40040'.
Are there some different interpretations of XSLT?

Comment: How the calculation is 1540 if we do in simple calculation its provide 1534?

Comment: @AmrendraKumar - Because of `ceiling()`.  Instead of `153.4 * 10` it's `154 * 10`.

Comment: What version of xsltproc are you using? I'm unable to reproduce using 1.1.26.win32.

Comment: @DanielHaley, Is it depends on processor? i use to calculate without `ceiling()` and again the value is `1534`. Please refer link: http://xsltransform.net/6qaFCEe. Its curiosity to know deeply. Thanks

Comment: @AmrendraKumar - without ceiling it’s 1534 (153.4 * 10). With ceiling it’s 1540 (154 * 10). http://xsltransform.net/6qaFCEe/1

Comment: I figured out the error - all operation in line was executed twice - not by mistake of xsltproc but by my mistake. There was typo in command, I put "-o" (file output) at the end of command and it coused error. It seems like it working fine (new file was created with content) but runs twice.. so 59*26*26=1540*26 = 40040 (ceiling also twice)